# How can i generate a combination by the position

Tags: algorithm, math

One example i have a set of numbers [1,2,3], and the position 4 and i want to generate it without repetitions.

```
1: [1,1,1]
2: [2,1,1]
3: [1,2,1]
4: [.....]
```

Comment: You must specify what do you mean by "combination"

Comment: And how they are ordered.

Comment: Is lexicographically ordered

Comment: This example does not resemble lex ordering. Give full list

Comment: 1: [1,1,1]
2: [1,1,2]
3: [1,1,3]
4: [.....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at you previous topic, I can suggest that you want to generate `N^M` combinations of N possible digits of length M with repeats. Note that every combination corresponds to integer value in range `0..N^M-1`, so we can generate such values and represend them in N-ary numeral system. Python code:

```
def GenCombs(N, M):
    lst = [0]*M
    for v in range(N**M):
        t = v
        for i in range(M):
            d = t % N
            lst[M - i - 1] = d + 1
            t = t // N
        print(lst)
```

To generate the only K-th combination (numbered from zero), make excerpt:

```
def GenComb(N, M, K):
    lst = [0]*M
    for i in range(M):
        d = K % N
        lst[M - i - 1] = d + 1
        K = K // N
    return(lst)

print(GenComb(3, 3, 11))  

>>>  [2, 1, 3]
```